# JSON.stringify not making proper json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making an API service to send data to my API endpoint but I'm having a bit of trouble with it.

```
function getStockLevel(articleCodes) {
var ajaxCallData = [], stockLevels = [];

articleCodes.forEach(function(articleCode) {
    if (isLocalStorageSupported() === true) {
        if (localStorage.getItem(articleCode) === null) {
            ajaxCallData.push(articleCode);
        } else {
            var localData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(articleCode));

            if ((Date.now() / 1000) >= localData['timestamp']) {
                ajaxCallData.push(articleCode);
            } else {
                stockLevels[articleCode] = localData['stock'];
            }
        }
    } else {
        ajaxCallData.push(articleCode);
    }
});

if (typeof ajaxCallData !== 'undefined' && ajaxCallData.length > 0) {
    var article_codes = JSON.stringify(ajaxCallData);

    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        dataType : 'json',
        type : 'POST',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        data : {
            article_codes : article_codes
        },
        success : function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            for (var code in result) {
                if (result.hasOwnProperty(code)) {
                    var stockLevel = result[code];

                    stockLevels[code] = stockLevel;

                    if (isLocalStorageSupported() === true) {
                        var localStorageData = [];
                        localStorageData['stock'] = stockLevel;
                        localStorageData['timestamp'] = (Date.now() / 1000) + 120;

                        localStorage.setItem(code, JSON.stringify(localStorageData))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
}

var codes = [40200, 40201];
var result = getStockLevel(codes);
```

I am using Ajax and jQuery to send an array of integers to my endpoint but if I check the data that's coming into my endpoint it returns: `article_codes=%5B40200%2C40201%5D` instead of the json I am expecting.

If I pass the ajaxCallData directly to the data property of the ajax call I get the same result except both values have the same key like so:

```
article_codes=40200&article_codes=40201
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The whole purpose of using jQuery and `dataType : 'json',` is to have all this stuff done automatically. If you encode things and set headers yourself you're possibly just interfering.

Comment: Try not doing -> `contentType : 'application/json'`  you have set dataType anyway.  Also are you sure it's not the PHP end?, what does you network tab in say chrome show?

Answer (score 0):

```
data : ajaxCallData
```

Try Passing it in like this.

ajaxCallData already was an object with the articles_codes set as a key.
You don't need to JSON.stringify it at all.

Comment: If I pass it that way I get this in my php script: undefined=&undefined=

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Balthasar was pretty close actually.
I needed to set the data like so data : article_codes

I now get the proper data in my endpoint controller.

Thanks for the help everyone!